# Getting pdfLaTeX ro run on new install (Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: pdftex, installing, mactex, mac

New laptop, and attempting to set up TeXShop . I downloaded MacTeX, and attempted to install (using install-tl), but Terminal said I did not have permission. Found instructions to enable root user, placed the MacTeX in a Shared folder, logged in as root user and ran install-tl. Install seemed successful, but when I log back into my user account, pdfLaTeX does not run. Following message comes up:

> /usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. Perhaps TeXLive was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to the TeXShop web site and follow the instructions to (re)install TeXLive. Another possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the fink teTeX distribution.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, and likely something silly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: MacTex should be simple to install. You shouldn't have to enable root.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you downloaded. If you get MacTeX it's a Mac installer bundle, so there should be no `install-tl` involved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found the pdflatex file, and changed the path to it via Preferences in TexShop. Let's hope that gets things working!

Comment: You *definitely* don't have to enable the root user. The installation of MacTeX is simple: double-click on the file you download from [TUG](http://tug.org/mactex), press a couple of OK and type the administrator password when requested. On a one-user machine this is just the user's password.

Comment: Just to make sure: You did download `MacTex.pkg` from the [MacTeX website](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2012/), and not the generic Unix installer `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` (or similar) from the [texlive website](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did changing the path solve your problem? Did you really use the `MacTex.pkg`? Please give some feedback, otherwise your question might be closed (but can be [reopened](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1015)). Also think about registering your TeX.SX account!

Comment: @egreg yes but how to get the commandline version working? I am struggling with this [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129613/by-which-pkg-to-visualize-a-hypercube-graph#comment292060_129635), I have used TeXShop for now but it looks like I need to start using the commandline version even though the TeXShop is so nice or?

Comment: @hhh I use the command line more often than not; just `pdflatex file` from a Terminal window will do.