# Installation on OSX 10.7.4

Tags: installing, mac

I used the `mpkg`. Installation went fine, but nothing works. I cannot typeset (the usual "`/usr/texbin/pdflatex` does not exist"). TeXLive cannot find a server to connect to. I tried reinstalling from the `mpkg`, logging off/on, restarting, etc etc...

I see a softlink called `/usr/texbin` that points to `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin` 
but there is no TeX folder in `/Library`.

I do see a `TeXShop/` folder in `~/Library`.

The command `sudo find / -name "pdflatex*" -ls` returns some paths to `pdflatexc` or `pdflatexmk.engine` but nothing called `pdflatex`.

P.s. OSX 10.7.4.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. A duplicate of this question should be remove from the answers to [Getting pdfLaTeX ro run on new install (Mac OS X Lion)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74196/getting-pdflatex-ro-run-on-new-install-mac-os-x-lion/74393#74393)

Comment: *What* mpkg? Last time I looked, tug.org served a .pkg, not .mpkg. Right now it seems to be down, so I can't recheck. `MacTeX2012.pkg` installs into `/usr/local/texlive/2012/`. The symlink you found is just the first of a chain that should get you there. There should be a panel “TeX distribution” in system preferences to pick the distribution. It works by changing those symlinks.

Comment: hmmm - I must've downloaded the wrong thing. It had DVD in the filename and was <600MB. I am now downloading the MacTeX pkg that is 2.1GB. I'm sure this'll fix it. Thanks a lot for the comments henrique and Harald...