# How to draw 3-cube Gray code?

Tags: graphs

If reflected gray codes are generated inductively then one can use two copies of 2-cubes to generate a 3-cube. This is what I am trying to illustrate. So I drew two copies of 2-cubes, but when I connect them with a straight line, I get a rather poor picture. I have attached the image and the latex code that I am using.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
 \node (a) at (0,0,0) {$0000$};

 \node (b) at (1,0,0) {$0001$};
 \node (c) at (1,1,0) {$0101$};
 \node (d) at (0,1,0) {$0100$};

 \node (e) at (0,0,1) {$0010$};
 \node (f) at (1,0,1) {$0011$};
 \node (g) at (1,1,1) {$0111$};
 \node (h) at (0,1,1) {$0110$};
 ----------
 \node (a1) at (4,4,3) {$1000$};

 \node (b1) at (5,4,3) {$1001$};
 \node (c1) at (5,5,3) {$1101$};
 \node (d1) at (4,5,3) {$1100$};

 \node (e1) at (4,4,4) {$1010$};
 \node (f1) at (5,4,4) {$1011$};
 \node (g1) at (5,5,4) {$1111$};
 \node (h1) at (4,5,4) {$1110$};


 \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (a);
 \draw (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- (e);
 \draw(a) -- (e);
 \draw (d) -- (h);
 \draw (b) -- (f);
 \draw (c) -- (g);

  \draw (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (d1) -- (a1);
 \draw (e1) -- (f1) -- (g1) -- (h1) -- (e1);
 \draw(a1) -- (e1);
 \draw (d1) -- (h1);
 \draw (b1) -- (f1);
 \draw (c1) -- (g1);

 \draw (a) -- (a1);
 \draw (b) -- (b1);
 \draw (c) -- (c1);
 \draw (d) -- (d1);
 \draw (e) -- (e1);
 \draw (f) -- (f1);
 \draw (g) -- (g1);
 \draw (h) -- (h1);



 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Image: 
[image]

The connections between various nodes are not clear in this image. What can I do to make this illustration better?

Comment: What do you mean with not clear? A raster image can never be fully clear at all levels.

Comment: Check out [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gray-code-in-4-cube/)

Comment: I'd just move the top cube down a bit so the connecting lines were not forming a diagonal of the first face

Comment: Also plenty of hypercubes in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129613/116936).