# Undefined control sequence \thetkz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, undefined, tkz-berge

I'm using pdfLaTeX in MikTeX 2.9.  I'm trying to create the hypercube in NamedGraphs.pdf (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129972/200958):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
%\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\grCycle[RA=8]{8}
\pgfmathparse{8*(1-4*sin(22.5)*sin(22.5))}
\let\tkzbradius\pgfmathresult
\grCirculant[prefix=b,RA=\tkzbradius]{8}{3}
\makeatletter
\foreach \vx in {0,...,7}{%
\pgfmathsetcounter{tkz@gr@n}{mod(\vx+1,8)}
\pgfmathsetcounter{tkz@gr@a}{mod(\vx+7,8)}
\pgfmathsetcounter{tkz@gr@b}{mod(\thetkz@gr@n+1,8)}
\Edge(a\thetkz@gr@n)(b\thetkz@gr@b)
\Edge(b\thetkz@gr@a)(a\vx)
}
\makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
\end{document}
```

The code above works.  But if I include the tikzpicture in a frame (that is, if I remove the comment symbol for "\frame{" and "}"), I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> mod(\thetkz 
                       @gr@n+1,8)
l.20 }
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Replace `\frame{` with `\begin{frame}[fragile]` and `}` with `\end{frame}` and your code should be compilable again.

Comment: @leandriis Wow, it worked!  Please write your comment as an answer so that I can upvote and accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your code compilable, you can use `\begin{frame}[fragile] ... \end{frame}` instead of `\frame{ ... }`. You might also want to add something along the lines of `[scale=0.4]` to your `tikzpicture` environment in order to make sure the image fits onto the slide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\grCycle[RA=8]{8}
\pgfmathparse{8*(1-4*sin(22.5)*sin(22.5))}
\let\tkzbradius\pgfmathresult
\grCirculant[prefix=b,RA=\tkzbradius]{8}{3}
\makeatletter
\foreach \vx in {0,...,7}{%
\pgfmathsetcounter{tkz@gr@n}{mod(\vx+1,8)}
\pgfmathsetcounter{tkz@gr@a}{mod(\vx+7,8)}
\pgfmathsetcounter{tkz@gr@b}{mod(\thetkz@gr@n+1,8)}
\Edge(a\thetkz@gr@n)(b\thetkz@gr@b)
\Edge(b\thetkz@gr@a)(a\vx)
}
\makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry it took me some time to upvote and accept this.  I was away.